# [stderr]master failed to start, check stderr log for details. AWS | EC2 | Ubuntu | Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, unicorn, elastic-load-balancer

When requests come to my server at the time of deployment, it got failed.
I'm using Ubuntu in AWS EC2. As I'm using Elastic Load Balancer, I have tried my instance to deregister from and again register with Load Balancer so that meanwhile I can start unicorn server. Also before starting unicorn I'm removing **unicorn.pid**

```
inst=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)`
aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer --load-balancer-name my_load_balancer_name --instances $inst

echo "Server deregistered from Load Balancer"

sleep 10s

file="/home/ubuntu/pids/unicorn.pid"
if [ -f $file ];
 then
  echo "File found:"
  ls /home/ubuntu/pids/ 
  rm ~/pids/unicorn.pid 
  echo "unicorn.pid removed"
  ls /home/ubuntu/pids/ #cross-checking the removal of the unicorn.pid
  echo "if you see \"unicorn.pid removed\" message just above this line, it means unicorn.pid removed successfully"
else
  echo "$file not found"
fi

RAILS_ENV=qa bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D #this command is giving error "[stderr]master failed to start, check stderr log for details" `
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

**stderr logs**

I, [2017-02-22T14:44:12.773724 #12531]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:21.233361 #12531] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock (in use)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:21.233422 #12531] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:21.733925 #12531] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock (in use)
E, [2017-02-22T14:44:21.734008 #12531] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (3 tries left)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:22.234528 #12531] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock (in use)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:22.234626 #12531] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (2 tries left)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:22.735121 #12531] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock (in use)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:22.738710 #12531] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (1 tries left)
E, [2017-02-22T14:44:23.239213 #12531] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock (in use)
E, [2017-02-22T14:44:23.239293 #12531] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (0 tries left)

E, [2017-02-22T14:44:23.739818 #12531] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock (in use)

Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - connect(2) for /home/ubuntu/unicorn.sock"

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:158:in `initialize'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:158:in `new'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:158:in `bind_listen'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:242:in `listen'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:813:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:813:in `each'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:813:in `bind_new_listeners!'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:138:in `start'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:22:in `load'

/home/ubuntu/ZenSol/curr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:22:in `'
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-193:~/log$

Comment: then check the stderr log file for error message and paste it here.

Comment: @sam, Thank you for replying. I have attached the logs.

Comment: check your unicornr.rb config file, I think you need to comment out a like this:

Comment: listen "127.0.0.1:port", :tcp_nopush => true

Comment: Sorry @sam, but I did not find anything like this in my unicorn.rb file.

Comment: which port you are running unicorn on? use this command to see if the port is open, close it and also kill the process. then run again, if still doesn't work, run your unicorn on a different port, you can do that in settings files. the command is :     lsof -wni tcp:portnumber